# Does my system support VT?

Tags: macos, mac, iphone

I'm trying to use OSX86 on my Intel based machine. THe OS i have is Feodora-9 Sulphur.

I read that the processor should support SSe2 or SSe3 for OSX86 compatibility.

This is what my cpuinfo is:

Can you please let me know if it suits it:

[root@localhost ~]# cat /proc/cpuinfo

processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 23
model name      : Pentium(R) Dual-Core  CPU      E5200  @ 2.50GHz
stepping        : 6
cpu MHz         : 1200.000
cache size      : 2048 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 2
core id         : 0
cpu cores       : 2
apicid          : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fdiv_bug        : no
hlt_bug         : no
f00f_bug        : no
coma_bug        : no
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 10
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts pni monitor ds_cpl est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr lahf_lm
bogomips        : 4999.79
clflush size    : 64
power management:

processor       : 1
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 23
model name      : Pentium(R) Dual-Core  CPU      E5200  @ 2.50GHz
stepping        : 6
cpu MHz         : 1200.000
cache size      : 2048 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 2
core id         : 1
cpu cores       : 2
apicid          : 1
initial apicid  : 1
fdiv_bug        : no
hlt_bug         : no
f00f_bug        : no
coma_bug        : no
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 10
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts pni monitor ds_cpl est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr lahf_lm
bogomips        : 4999.62
clflush size    : 64
power management:

Also, Please let me know if i need to give any additional info.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not have VT-X.

Specs for a E5200: http://processorfinder.intel.com/details.aspx?sSpec=SLAY7
If it did, then under the Supported Features table would be "Intel® Virtualization Technology".

I don't know whether the lack of VT-X is causing problems with running OS X in a VM, but it's notoriously tricky to get going even with VT-X support.